# Htaccess URL Rewrite catching 2 or 5 characters (but not 3 or 4)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My current rewrite rule to catch the selected language is this:

```
RewriteRule ^language/([A-Za-z-]{2,5})/?$ /yadayada.php?hl=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So it will catch these:

- /language/es (spanish)
- /language/de (german)

But, language codes can only contain 2 letters (eg: en, es, de) or 5 letters (eg: zh-TW). The problem is that it should **not** accept any of these (3 or 4 letters, or all 5 lowercased letters):

- /language/esp (three letters)
- /language/zh-tw (using lowercase letters in the 2nd part, it must be zh-TW)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would split it up then:

```
RewriteRule ^language/([a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2})/?$ /yadayada.php?hl=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Match if there are 2 lowercased letters (e.g. 'de' or 'en' or 'fr') **or** if there are 2 lowercased letters followed by a dash and 2 uppercased letters (e.g. 'zh-TW' or 'zh-CN').